# Translate more than one string in iOS with Google Translate API

Tags: ios, swift, google-translate

I am trying to translate some strings with [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text), but I can't translate more than one string at time with the latest vesrsion of API. I am using Alamofire to make request but when I try create parameter dictionary with the same key as in docs, it fails of course. The parameters should be in this format.

> {   'q': 'Hello world',
>       'q': 'My name is Jeff',
>       'target': 'de' }

Anybody has some ideas on how to send this request with same key on parameters?

Comment: That is not a valid JSON

Comment: Yes I know. But how can I make a request like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I made it work was altering the httpBody of the request.

```
    var requestBody = "{"
    for (_, value) in allText {
        requestBody.append("\'q\':\'\(value)\',")
    }
    requestBody.append("\'source\':\'\(Language.english.rawValue)\',")
    requestBody.append("\'target\':\'\(language.rawValue)\'")
    requestBody.append("}")

    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = jsonData
```

And performing the request with Alamofire worked for me.

I don't really know why someone who can't provide a solution downvotes a question, but whatever, and hope will help someone who may run into similar task.